# favicon.ico not displaying in spring mvc 3.2.2 per Tomcat 7.0?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, favicon

I'm new to spring mvc and my favicon.ico is not showing up in browser tab using spring 3.2.2 using tomcat 7.0.  I have tried looking at related googling but still cannot get it to show up in the browser tab (FF, Chrome, IE...all latest versions to not work) as well as clearing cache and restarting browser.

- favicon.ico

> Located in root of webapp folder (src/main/webapp)

- index.jsp

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>  
>       <html> 
>          <head>         
>             <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" >
>   o o o
> ```

- mvc-dispatcher-server.xml

> ```
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.website.controllers" />
>
> <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>   <property name="prefix">
>       <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
>   </property>
>   <property name="suffix">
>       <value>.jsp</value>
>   </property>
> </bean>
> ```

- web.xml

> > ```
> > <welcome-file-list>
> >     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
> > </welcome-file-list>
> > ```

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the icon is served, i.e. make a request to /favicon.ico and see if it renders.

If it does, add this to your web.xml to make sure Tomcat sends the correct `Content-Type` with the response:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Make sure `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` is present if you map the dispatcher servlet to `/`.

Comment: thx for the reply. when I request, http://localhost:8080/mysite/favicon.ico i get a 404 (even when i put the mime-mapping in the web.xml)......HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.12

Comment: Have you configured <mvc:default-servlet-handler />? See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler

Comment: I have this mapped in my web.xml (using spring 3.2.2Release)...so I'm assuming that it achieves the same thing.  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Put the <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> in your spring mvc config, otherwise resources normally served by Tomcat won't work.

Comment: SUCCESS! Thanks Jukka!  =)

Comment: QQ: Is there anything special I need to do to change from href="favicon.ico" to href="/images/favicon.ico"?

Comment: Well if "images" is a directory under src/main/webapp, then the only thing you need to change is to make it href="/mysite/images/favicon.ico", assuming your app is rooted at /mysite.