# favicon.ico doesn't displayed in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, favicon

I am trying to add a favicon.ico using spring mvc 4 and apache tomcat 7 (in firefox).
I examined many solutions but no one seems to work.

web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

mvc-core-config.xml:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css" /> -->
<mvc:resources location="/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />
```

jsp:

```
<link href="MYPROJECT/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

(I also tried without MYPROJECT and other variations...).

I placed favicon.ico file right under webapps (tried in other folders as well).

When loading the page, no icon displayed.

**Note**: I tried to load directly the icon `http://localhost:8080/MYPROJECT/favicon.ico` but received the following error message: `the image 'http://localhost:8080/MYPROJECT/favicon.ico' cannot be displayed because it contains errors`. I downloaded other favicon.ico but the icon looks corrupted.

When inspecting elements in firefox I don't ant call to the favicon.ico.

Any suggestion?

**Update:**
in my eclipse console I see:

> Looking up handler method for path /
>   15:48:05.622 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/]
>   15:48:05.622 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /
>   15:48:05.623 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/]
>   15:48:05.623 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@380baa3a] and 1 interceptor

**Update2**
mvc config xml:

```
<import resource="mvc-view-config.xml"/>
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>     
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>   
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers,logic.preprocess"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<mvc:resources location="/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:basename="messages/messages"/>

</beans>
```

The included mvc-view-config.xml:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"></property>
            </bean>


<bean       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
<property name="order" value="1"/> </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="order" value="2" /> </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
     <property name="order" value="3" />
     <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
     <property name="mappings">
     <props>
         <prop key="controllers/TaskController">taskController</prop>
         <prop key="controllers/ResultController">resultController</prop>
     </props>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

**update 3**
I placed the file under resources/images and it seems to work PARTIALLY (without shortcut) only on chrome but not on firefox.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

**Tested in FireFox and Chrome:** I had the same problem. Here is how to solve it.  I've done what [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17179279/537566):

*web.xml:*

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

*mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:*

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" />
```

(No need for `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in my case)

*genericpage.tag (I use templates, but this can be your jsp file):*

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href='<c:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico" />' type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href='<c:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico" />' type="image/x-icon">
```

**NB:** Note that you have to use the `<c:rul value=` bit in the href else it will not work.

*Project structure:*

```
Web pages
+--META-INF
+--WEB-INF
+--resources
   +--mytheme
      +--css
      +--images
         +--favicon.ico
```

For some reason it doesn't work when it is just in /resources/mytheme/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  So ridiculous that it takes this much work to get a favicon to show lol.

Answer (score 1):

store favicon.ico -  one up from WEB-INF directory.

```
 <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. See my update `Did not find handler method for [/]` - maybe it's related?

Comment: can u post the rest of your mvc config.xml?

Comment: When inspecting elements in firefox I don't ant call to the favicon.ico.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below tag in your web application dispatcher servlet i.e.

```
springmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:
```

Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" 
        cache-period="45556999"/>
```

Your web application structure should be like below

[image: web_application_structure]

Your web application WebContent  folder structure should be like below

```xml
WebContent

+resources
     -->images
    -->favicon.ico
```

Put these line in your web application jsp pages in-between `<header></header>` tag like below

```html
<head>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href='<c:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico" />'     type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href='<c:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico" />' type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```